# Посчитать рейтинг в процентном отношении в JS

Tags: javascript, база-данных

словил затуп

в базе хранятся отзывы о магазине

- id
- userId
- rating

как посчитать в процентном отношении рейтинг магазина

если все 5-ки это 100%

а поле rating хранит от 0 до 5 значения

Comment: Получите AVG поля rating, далее это значение делим на 5 и умножаем на 100 - будет %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять среднее арифметическое оценок и отнормировать к 5 (разделить на 5). Таким образом, в крайних случаях:

- если все оценки == 0, то рейтинг будет 0/5 = 0%
- если все оценки == 5, то рейтинг будет 5/5 = 100%
- если, например, оценки 5 и 4, то ((5+4)/2)/5 = 4,5/5 = 90%

```js
function rating(arr) {
    return 'Рейтинг магазина = ' + (arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0) / arr.length / 5 * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
}

console.log(rating([3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3]))
```

Comment: как-то так `select avg(rating)/5 from reviews`